# Windows Home Server: Can't see my RAID 5?

Tags: raid-5, windows-home-server

Motherboard: ASUS A8N SLI-Deluxe

I've got a RAID 5 goin' on and there's no problem with my Windows 7 drive seeing the RAID.

But, I wanted to switch out my Windows 7 HDD for a fresh Windows Home Server install and now I can't see my RAID 5 setup.

I went to the ASUS website and installed the Windows 2003 64-bit software (which can see the drives), but I'm not sure how to install the accompanied driver...

Comment: This would be better on Superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I know why... you're supposed to have the RAID5 drivers on a USB before you install the OS and when WHS asks you about your installed drives, you need to click on the "Load drives" and select your USB with the RAID5 drivers on there. Then you should see the Secondary set of drives...

The installation will continue on the Primary HDD so you don't have to worry about losing any data that you might have on your RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Open device manager, find the RAID controller, right click, update driver, point to USB drive (or wherever you have the driver). Same procedure for just about every version of Windows in the last 10 years.

Comment: That's nice. The last 10 years are absolutely worthless to those who have never needed to do it before. But thanks for the sarcasm... it helped.

Comment: You posted on a site exclusively for Professional System Administrators. I don't suppose you tried Googling "install device driver" either. The sarcasm was not meant as such (though it sounds worse reading it back); simply stating that it's the same procedure for many different versions of Windows. Re-installation as your "answer" suggests is unnecessary.